# Where is the all Android broadcast Intent list

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

I want to receive the Android broadcast messages. Is there a list of all intents?

Comment: 7+ years have passed and yet google hasn't bothered to give a reference list in its documentation?

Comment: Here is the list:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/platforms/android-28/data/broadcast_actions.txt

Answer (score 107):

I have found the broadcast intent list. It can be located under the `sdks(or android-sdks)/platforms/<android-sdk-version>/data/broadcast_actions.txt`.

Comment: android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE seems to be a valid broadcast intent but i couldn't find it on the broadcast_actions.txt

Comment: For the lazy, default path on Windows 7 64-bit: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\broadcast_actions.txt"`

Comment: @lock Yes it is (kitkat)

Comment: Why is this answer such highly voted? It could've listed/linked the text file to make this useful. It makes no sense  to download SDK just for this list.

Comment: For me its in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\data\broadcast_actions.txt`

Answer (score 42):

For API level 16 (ICS), this is the list:

```
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRING
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.LOCAL_NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND
android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH
android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.pan.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE
android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO
android.hardware.input.action.QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW
android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED
android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.FETCH_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.GTALK_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.GTALK_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED
android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.MANAGE_PACKAGE_STORAGE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.MEDIA_CHECKING
android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT
android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_NOFS
android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SHARED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL
android.intent.action.NEW_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE
android.intent.action.REBOOT
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED
android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY
android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED
android.media.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.media.VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED
android.media.action.CLOSE_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED
android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE
android.provider.Telephony.SIM_FULL
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CB_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_EMERGENCY_CB_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_REJECTED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SERVICE_CATEGORY_PROGRAM_DATA_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED
android.speech.tts.TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED
android.speech.tts.engine.TTS_DATA_INSTALLED
```

Comment: Source for this? It also seems some are missing, ie. `android.intent.action.PICK`, added in API level 1: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK

Comment: As @JanSchejbal points out, I found it in my "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\broadcast_actions.txt" file. I wanted to update it for api 17, but there were some in 16 that weren't in 17 that I know are still implemented like Telephony ones. I don't know why PICK is missing, but at the same time, I don't know why Telephony is missing in my file for 17. This list is straight from my file.

Answer (score 19):

*** API level 21**

```
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRING
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED
android.app.action.LOCK_TASK_ENTERING
android.app.action.LOCK_TASK_EXITING
android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED
android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.LOCAL_NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND
android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST
android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH
android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.pan.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE
android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO
android.hardware.hdmi.action.OSD_MESSAGE
android.hardware.input.action.QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.CONTENT_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED
android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE
android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STARTED
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.FETCH_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.GTALK_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.GTALK_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED
android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.MANAGE_PACKAGE_STORAGE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.MEDIA_CHECKING
android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT
android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED android.intent.action.MEDIA_NOFS
android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SHARED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL
android.intent.action.NEW_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERIFIED
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE android.intent.action.REBOOT
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIME_SET android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED
android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED
android.media.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.media.VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED
android.media.action.CLOSE_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.media.action.HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG
android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.scoring.SCORER_CHANGED
android.net.scoring.SCORE_NETWORKS
android.net.wifi.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE
android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED
android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED
android.provider.Telephony.SIM_FULL
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CB_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_EMERGENCY_CB_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_REJECTED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SERVICE_CATEGORY_PROGRAM_DATA_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED
android.speech.tts.TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED
android.speech.tts.engine.TTS_DATA_INSTALLED
```

Updated Broadcast intents list for Android API level 21.

Comment: I don't know any url . actually we can access this information in the directory sdk's platform /data/broadcast_actions.txt (answered by batfree). But I wanted to show all information directly here instead going to directory.

Answer (score 12):

Here is the [Intent reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and here is nice read about [Intents and Intent-Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) and another interesting read about [whether you can use that intent](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html).

All located on the developer site of Android. This is the first place you should always search.

Comment: at Octavian, in my view, your answer does not address the question. batfree is asking for a list of all broadcast events. This is a legitimate question because there are more than those listed in the Intent class; see lock's comment above for example.

Comment: Nice read, but sadly no answer to the question as said above.

Answer (score 8):

The List can be easily found at .android-sdks\platforms\android-17\data\broadcast_actions.

```
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRING
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.LOCAL_NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND
android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH
android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.pan.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE
android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO
android.hardware.input.action.QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW
android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STARTED
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.FETCH_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.GTALK_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.GTALK_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED
android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.MANAGE_PACKAGE_STORAGE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.MEDIA_CHECKING
android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT
android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_NOFS
android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SHARED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL
android.intent.action.NEW_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERIFIED
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE
android.intent.action.REBOOT
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED
android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY
android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED
android.media.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.media.VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED
android.media.action.CLOSE_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED
android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE
android.speech.tts.TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED
android.speech.tts.engine.TTS_DATA_INSTALLED
```

Answer (score 6):

Current version (1.3) of Android Studio will give you a list if you press CTRL + SPACE like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

New updated list, API level 27

```
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRING
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED
android.app.action.DEVICE_OWNER_CHANGED
android.app.action.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_CHANGED
android.app.action.LOCK_TASK_ENTERING
android.app.action.LOCK_TASK_EXITING
android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_CHANGED
android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE
android.app.action.SYSTEM_UPDATE_POLICY_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.LOCAL_NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND
android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST
android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH
android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.pan.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE
android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO
android.hardware.hdmi.action.OSD_MESSAGE
android.hardware.input.action.QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW
android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.CONTENT_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED
android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE
android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STARTED
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.FETCH_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.GTALK_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.GTALK_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED
android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.MANAGE_PACKAGE_STORAGE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.MEDIA_CHECKING
android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT
android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_NOFS
android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SHARED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL
android.intent.action.NEW_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.PACKAGES_SUSPENDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGES_UNSUSPENDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERIFIED
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE
android.intent.action.REBOOT
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SYNC_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
android.intent.action.USER_UNLOCKED
android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED
android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY
android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED
android.media.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.media.VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED
android.media.action.CLOSE_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.media.action.HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG
android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
android.net.conn.RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_CHANGED
android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.scoring.SCORER_CHANGED
android.net.scoring.SCORE_NETWORKS
android.net.wifi.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE
android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED
android.os.action.DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED
android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED
android.provider.Telephony.SIM_FULL
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CB_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_REJECTED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SERVICE_CATEGORY_PROGRAM_DATA_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED
android.provider.action.DEFAULT_SMS_PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.provider.action.EXTERNAL_PROVIDER_CHANGE
android.speech.tts.TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED
android.speech.tts.engine.TTS_DATA_INSTALLED
```

Answer (score 5):

Well i have a method by which i get all the intents list, may not be an official one but works pretty well.

Open the Manifest file(AndroidManifest.xml) of your project, put the following code snippet below inside the "Application" Tag.

```
<receiver 
    android:name="test"
    android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android."/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Next step put the cursor in intent-filter section after "android." and press Ctrl + Space.

You would get all the possible intents as a pop up and you can then copy the list wherever you want.

Don't forget to remove the above code from Manifest, when you are done.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

**New Updated List for API Level 28: 'Android-N'**

```
android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED
android.accounts.action.ACCOUNT_REMOVED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRING
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED
android.app.action.APPLICATION_DELEGATION_SCOPES_CHANGED
android.app.action.APP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED
android.app.action.DEVICE_OWNER_CHANGED
android.app.action.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_CHANGED
android.app.action.LOCK_TASK_ENTERING
android.app.action.LOCK_TASK_EXITING
android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_GROUP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_CHANGED
android.app.action.PROFILE_OWNER_CHANGED
android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE
android.app.action.SYSTEM_UPDATE_POLICY_CHANGED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_HOST_RESTORED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_RESTORED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE_OPTIONS
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.LOCAL_NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND
android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST
android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH
android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.hearingaid.profile.action.ACTIVE_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.hearingaid.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.hearingaid.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.hiddevice.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.pan.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.pbap.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.content.pm.action.SESSION_COMMITTED
android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE
android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO
android.hardware.hdmi.action.OSD_MESSAGE
android.hardware.input.action.QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW
android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.CONTENT_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED
android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE
android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STARTED
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED
android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.FACTORY_RESET
android.intent.action.FETCH_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.GTALK_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.GTALK_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED
android.intent.action.INTENT_FILTER_NEEDS_VERIFICATION
android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.MANAGE_PACKAGE_STORAGE
android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR_NOTIFICATION
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.MEDIA_CHECKING
android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT
android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_NOFS
android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SHARED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_SUSPENDED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_UNSUSPENDED
android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL
android.intent.action.NEW_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.PACKAGES_SUSPENDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGES_UNSUSPENDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERIFIED
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.REBOOT
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SPLIT_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
android.intent.action.USER_UNLOCKED
android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED
android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY
android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED
android.media.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.media.VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED
android.media.action.CLOSE_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.media.action.HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG
android.media.action.MICROPHONE_MUTE_CHANGED
android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.media.tv.action.CHANNEL_BROWSABLE_REQUESTED
android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS
android.media.tv.action.PREVIEW_PROGRAM_ADDED_TO_WATCH_NEXT
android.media.tv.action.PREVIEW_PROGRAM_BROWSABLE_DISABLED
android.media.tv.action.WATCH_NEXT_PROGRAM_BROWSABLE_DISABLED
android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
android.net.conn.RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_CHANGED
android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.scoring.SCORER_CHANGED
android.net.scoring.SCORE_NETWORKS
android.net.wifi.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.aware.action.WIFI_AWARE_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.rtt.action.WIFI_RTT_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE
android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED
android.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_DETECTED
android.os.action.DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED
android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED
android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE
android.provider.Telephony.SIM_FULL
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CB_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_REJECTED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SERVICE_CATEGORY_PROGRAM_DATA_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED
android.provider.action.DEFAULT_SMS_PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.provider.action.EXTERNAL_PROVIDER_CHANGE
android.provider.action.SYNC_VOICEMAIL
android.security.STORAGE_CHANGED
android.security.action.KEYCHAIN_CHANGED
android.security.action.KEY_ACCESS_CHANGED
android.security.action.TRUST_STORE_CHANGED
android.speech.tts.TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED
android.speech.tts.engine.TTS_DATA_INSTALLED
android.telephony.action.DEFAULT_SMS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.DEFAULT_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.REFRESH_SUBSCRIPTION_PLANS
android.telephony.action.SIM_APPLICATION_STATE_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.SIM_CARD_STATE_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.SIM_SLOT_STATUS_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.SUBSCRIPTION_CARRIER_IDENTITY_CHANGED
android.telephony.euicc.action.NOTIFY_CARRIER_SETUP_INCOMPLETE
android.telephony.euicc.action.OTA_STATUS_CHANGED
```

Answer (score 3):

## Updated List API Level 30

```
android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED
android.accounts.action.ACCOUNT_REMOVED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRING
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED
android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED
android.app.action.AFFILIATED_PROFILE_TRANSFER_OWNERSHIP_COMPLETE
android.app.action.APPLICATION_DELEGATION_SCOPES_CHANGED
android.app.action.APP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED
android.app.action.AUTOMATIC_ZEN_RULE_STATUS_CHANGED
android.app.action.BUGREPORT_FAILED
android.app.action.BUGREPORT_SHARE
android.app.action.BUGREPORT_SHARING_DECLINED
android.app.action.DATA_SHARING_RESTRICTION_APPLIED
android.app.action.DATA_SHARING_RESTRICTION_CHANGED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED
android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED
android.app.action.DEVICE_OWNER_CHANGED
android.app.action.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_CHANGED
android.app.action.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_CHANGED_INTERNAL
android.app.action.LOCK_TASK_ENTERING
android.app.action.LOCK_TASK_EXITING
android.app.action.MANAGED_USER_CREATED
android.app.action.NETWORK_LOGS_AVAILABLE
android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_GROUP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_CHANGED
android.app.action.NOTIFY_PENDING_SYSTEM_UPDATE
android.app.action.PROFILE_OWNER_CHANGED
android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE
android.app.action.SECURITY_LOGS_AVAILABLE
android.app.action.SYSTEM_UPDATE_POLICY_CHANGED
android.app.action.TRANSFER_OWNERSHIP_COMPLETE
android.app.action.USER_ADDED
android.app.action.USER_REMOVED
android.app.action.USER_STARTED
android.app.action.USER_STOPPED
android.app.action.USER_SWITCHED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_HOST_RESTORED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_RESTORED
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE
android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE_OPTIONS
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.ACTIVE_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.AVRCP_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CODEC_CONFIG_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.LOCAL_NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED
android.bluetooth.device.action.ALIAS_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.BATTERY_LEVEL_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.CONNECTION_ACCESS_CANCEL
android.bluetooth.device.action.CONNECTION_ACCESS_REPLY
android.bluetooth.device.action.CONNECTION_ACCESS_REQUEST
android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND
android.bluetooth.device.action.MAS_INSTANCE
android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_FAILED
android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_CANCEL
android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST
android.bluetooth.device.action.SDP_RECORD
android.bluetooth.device.action.SILENCE_MODE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED
android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH
android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.ACTIVE_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.hearingaid.profile.action.ACTIVE_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.hearingaid.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.hiddevice.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.HANDSHAKE
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.IDLE_TIME_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.PROTOCOL_MODE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.REPORT
android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.VIRTUAL_UNPLUG_STATUS
android.bluetooth.pan.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.bluetooth.pbap.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
android.content.pm.action.SESSION_COMMITTED
android.content.pm.action.SESSION_UPDATED
android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE
android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO
android.hardware.hdmi.action.OSD_MESSAGE
android.hardware.input.action.QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED
android.intent.action.ACTION_IDLE_MAINTENANCE_END
android.intent.action.ACTION_IDLE_MAINTENANCE_START
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_PREFERRED_ACTIVITY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED
android.intent.action.APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW
android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.CALL_DISCONNECT_CAUSE
android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.CANCEL_ENABLE_ROLLBACK
android.intent.action.CLEAR_DNS_CACHE
android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.CONTENT_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED
android.intent.action.DATA_STALL_DETECTED
android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_FULL
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_NOT_FULL
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.DISTRACTING_PACKAGES_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE
android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STARTED
android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED
android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED
android.intent.action.DYNAMIC_SENSOR_CHANGED
android.intent.action.EMERGENCY_CALLBACK_MODE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.EMERGENCY_CALL_STATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.FACTORY_RESET
android.intent.action.FETCH_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.GTALK_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.GTALK_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED
android.intent.action.INTENT_FILTER_NEEDS_VERIFICATION
android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.MANAGE_PACKAGE_STORAGE
android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR_NOTIFICATION
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.MEDIA_CHECKING
android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT
android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_NOFS
android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SHARED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_SUSPENDED
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_UNSUSPENDED
android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL
android.intent.action.NEW_VOICEMAIL
android.intent.action.PACKAGES_SUSPENDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGES_UNSUSPENDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ENABLE_ROLLBACK
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_NEEDS_INTEGRITY_VERIFICATION
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_UNSUSPENDED_MANUALLY
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERIFIED
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.REBOOT
android.intent.action.ROLLBACK_COMMITTED
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SPLIT_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SUB_DEFAULT_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
android.intent.action.USER_UNLOCKED
android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED
android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY
android.media.INTERNAL_RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION
android.media.MASTER_MUTE_CHANGED_ACTION
android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED
android.media.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
android.media.STREAM_DEVICES_CHANGED_ACTION
android.media.STREAM_MUTE_CHANGED_ACTION
android.media.VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED
android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION
android.media.action.CLOSE_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.media.action.HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG
android.media.action.MICROPHONE_MUTE_CHANGED
android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION
android.media.action.SPEAKERPHONE_STATE_CHANGED
android.media.tv.action.CHANNEL_BROWSABLE_REQUESTED
android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS
android.media.tv.action.PREVIEW_PROGRAM_ADDED_TO_WATCH_NEXT
android.media.tv.action.PREVIEW_PROGRAM_BROWSABLE_DISABLED
android.media.tv.action.WATCH_NEXT_PROGRAM_BROWSABLE_DISABLED
android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED
android.net.conn.CAPTIVE_PORTAL_TEST_COMPLETED
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE
android.net.conn.INET_CONDITION_ACTION
android.net.conn.RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_CHANGED
android.net.conn.TETHER_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.scoring.SCORER_CHANGED
android.net.scoring.SCORE_NETWORKS
android.net.sip.action.SIP_CALL_OPTION_CHANGED
android.net.sip.action.SIP_INCOMING_CALL
android.net.sip.action.SIP_REMOVE_PROFILE
android.net.sip.action.SIP_SERVICE_UP
android.net.sip.action.START_SIP
android.net.wifi.BATCHED_RESULTS
android.net.wifi.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.action.WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION
android.net.wifi.action.WIFI_SCAN_AVAILABILITY_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.aware.action.WIFI_AWARE_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.rtt.action.WIFI_RTT_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE
android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE
android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED
android.nfc.action.PREFERRED_PAYMENT_CHANGED
android.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_DETECTED
android.os.action.ACTION_EFFECTS_SUPPRESSOR_CHANGED
android.os.action.DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED
android.os.action.LIGHT_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED
android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED
android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED_INTERNAL
android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGING
android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_TEMP_WHITELIST_CHANGED
android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_WHITELIST_CHANGED
android.os.action.UPDATE_EMERGENCY_NUMBER_DB
android.provider.Telephony.MMS_DOWNLOADED
android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE
android.provider.Telephony.SIM_FULL
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CARRIER_PROVISION
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CB_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_REJECTED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SERVICE_CATEGORY_PROGRAM_DATA_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED
android.provider.action.DEFAULT_SMS_PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.provider.action.EXTERNAL_PROVIDER_CHANGE
android.provider.action.SMS_EMERGENCY_CB_RECEIVED
android.provider.action.SMS_MMS_DB_CREATED
android.provider.action.SMS_MMS_DB_LOST
android.provider.action.SYNC_VOICEMAIL
android.security.STORAGE_CHANGED
android.security.action.KEYCHAIN_CHANGED
android.security.action.KEY_ACCESS_CHANGED
android.security.action.TRUST_STORE_CHANGED
android.service.controls.action.ADD_CONTROL
android.settings.ENABLE_MMS_DATA_REQUEST
android.speech.tts.TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED
android.speech.tts.engine.TTS_DATA_INSTALLED
android.telephony.action.AREA_INFO_UPDATED
android.telephony.action.DEFAULT_SMS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.DEFAULT_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.PRIMARY_SUBSCRIPTION_LIST_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.REFRESH_SUBSCRIPTION_PLANS
android.telephony.action.SECRET_CODE
android.telephony.action.SERVICE_PROVIDERS_UPDATED
android.telephony.action.SIM_APPLICATION_STATE_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.SIM_CARD_STATE_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.SIM_SLOT_STATUS_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.SUBSCRIPTION_CARRIER_IDENTITY_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.SUBSCRIPTION_PLANS_CHANGED
android.telephony.action.SUBSCRIPTION_SPECIFIC_CARRIER_IDENTITY_CHANGED
android.telephony.euicc.action.NOTIFY_CARRIER_SETUP_INCOMPLETE
android.telephony.euicc.action.OTA_STATUS_CHANGED
android.telephony.ims.action.WFC_IMS_REGISTRATION_ERROR
com.android.intent.action.DISMISS_KEYBOARD_SHORTCUTS
com.android.intent.action.SHOW_KEYBOARD_SHORTCUTS
com.android.internal.intent.action.ACTION_FORBIDDEN_NO_SERVICE_AUTHORIZATION
com.android.internal.provider.action.VOICEMAIL_SMS_RECEIVED
```

Comment: Can you please share a link as a reference.

Comment: as menioned moltiple times this file resides in "android" folder. the sdkmanager tool can download the package "platforms;android-30" containing it in the data folder

Answer (score 2):

In my point of view there is no such list. In the SDK directory there is a useful file "broadcast_actions.txt". But it is just the android API framework (android.), not the native applications (com.), and (obviously) neither third party applications. Only a small part of native applications provides documentation for their broadcast intents. For third party applications you should check on their documentation or the source code if available.

For example the android native camera app (com.android.camera) broadcasts this intent anytime a new picture is taken:

```
com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE
```

As far as I know it is possible to listen to all broadcast intents on the phone with logcat.

Comment: In my point of view there is no such list. In the SDK directory there is a useful file "broadcast_actions.txt". But it is just the android API framework (android.), not the native applications (com.), and (obviously) neither third party applications. Only a small part of native applications provides documentation for their broadcast intents. For third party applications you should check on their documentation or the source code if available. As far as I know it is possible to listen to all broadcast intents on the phone with logcat.

Comment: now that's a complete answer. Can you [edit] that information into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Android Intents Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: That doesn't even list android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED

Answer (score 0):

go to the path android-sdks\platforms\android-VERSION\data\broadcast_actions
you will get the file for different versions of android