# Android list of events/broadcast receivers

Tags: android, events

I am not sure what the proper name is. There is a possibility to listen to "events" e.g. an SMS is incoming. I was looking for a complete list, but couldn't find any. Maybe it is due to the fact that I don't know the name of that. Can anyone help?

Thanks, A.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15178266/2066079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "complete list".

Many broadcast `Intents` are documented on the `Intent` class. Some broadcast `Intents` are documented on other classes (e.g., `ConnectivityManager`, `TelephonyManager`). Some broadcast `Intents` are not documented and should not be used.

And those are just the ones in the OS.

Comment: Lets take the TelephonyManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html where is there the list of intents? For example SMS_RECEIVE I would expect to see, but I don't something like this.

Comment: @AndyAndroid: That is because `SMS_RECEIVE` is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: What so you mean it is not part of the SDK? For exmaple here http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/ there is a receiver mentioned.

Comment: @AndyAndroid: That is a blog post from an independent developer from over three years ago. Blog posts from that long ago related to Android should be ignored. There *was* a point in time when `SMS_RECEIVE` was part of the SDK, before Android devices were actually shipping. By the time of Android 1.0, they removed that broadcast from the SDK. It is still broadcast, and it is still part of the Android source code, but it is not part of the Android SDK.