# Is there an intent in the android system which is fired when a new software was installed?

Tags: android, android-intent, installation, broadcastreceiver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there on install event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227604/is-there-on-install-event-in-android)

An intent which i might catch with a broadcast receiver?

Comment: try reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4031776/1056359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android Developer Site:

```
public static final String ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED
```

(API level 1)

**Broadcast Action:** A new application package has been installed on the device. The data contains the name of the package. Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.

May include the following extras:

`EXTRA_UID` containing the integer uid assigned to the new package.
`EXTRA_REPLACING` is set to true if this is following an `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` broadcast for the same package.
This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

**Constant Value:** `"android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"`