# Recyclebin in android

Tags: java, android, recycle-bin

How to create Recycle bin in android.This recycle bin functionality should be same as recycle bin which we are using in windows operating system. for more explanation:If i delete any files,images,messages etc it should reach to recycle bin. is there any broadcast receiver to listen when we are deleting anything in the mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You can find broadcast actions in %your_path_to_android_sdk%\platforms\android-18\data\broadcast_actions.txt
Took it here
 [Where is the all Android broadcast Intent list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031740/where-is-the-all-android-broadcast-intent-list)

Also in android exists http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html but it fires a delition vroadcast only after event occured.