# System App auto starting

Tags: android

I am making a app for a android phone development company. I need to run the app in the background there should not be any user interaction like google play service. So I made a application and placed it in the "system/app" so that user can't uninstall the app but I need to open the application to run the service in the background how can I skip that.

Comment: This problem is already solved?

Comment: My requirement was to open a application at boot load WITHOUT A SINGLE TIME LUNCHING THE APP

Comment: Everybody given ans how to open the app at bootload but if you have not lunched the application for the first time bootload will never be called.

Comment: Yes, I solved a similar problem. I created a BootBroadcastReceiver and  launches the application from visual studies. Then i closed it. Then i tried turn off and on device but intnent did not come and the application does not start. I must after installing app close it and then run again on the device, and then it bootRecevier works. I think it's a problem with development time, but if you publish app through Google Play and standard installed, then should booRecevier work. Check it out (i am not in the deploynment phase)

Comment: I don't have any option to upload it in google play because it a product

Comment: well, when I get to the deployment phase, I'll know if it is ok (I hope it will be).

Comment: Have you got solution for this. If yes, then pls post your solution I had similar requirement, Thanks.

Comment: Not possible with out rotted device

Comment: Hi bumba , I got solution First thing if you application is system then you they your app will be in active state. You can use Boot_complete_receiver for launching service. Or If your app don't have any launch activty then it will work it is active state. you don't need to open app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149797/auto-start-service-after-booting-device-even-app-not-opened-atonce-android

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [Android BroadcastReceiver on startup - keep running when Activity is in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup)

Once you have broadcast receiver that is being called when system boots, you should start sticky service. Look here: [START_STICKY and START_NOT_STICKY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky)

That way your application will be started on system each system boot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should register for some [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)s, so it will start yous app. You can use for example the `boot_completed` action so like this:

```
public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Log.i("Autostart", "**********started************");
    }
}
```

and the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pack.saltriver" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <receiver android:name=".Autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

but you can use a different type, you just need to modify the name of the intent . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27601497/3162918) is the list of all BroadcastReceiver Intent.

Answer (score 0):

There are many intent filter you can use fro ex- boot completed or Power plugged.

In both cases you can use broadcast receiver to to launch the active.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pack.saltriver" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver android:name=".tart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```